# How to select a column without its name in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

how to

```
select name,family from student where name="X"
```

without its column name.

for example :

```
select "column1","column2" from student where "column1"="x"
```

or for example

```
select "1","2" from student where "1"="x"
```

"1" is column1
"2" is column2

i dont want to say columns name. i want to say just its number or other....
idont tired from select *. but  it just for that i dont know the columns name but i know where they are. my columns name are change every i want to read the file but its data are same, and the data are in the same columns in each file.

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT *` ?

Comment: @Aiias - That's terrible advice. `SELECT *` is bad practice.

Comment: Why do you want to use ordinals instead of column names? It means that if the column order/number changes (which _can_ happen) your query will no longer return what you think it does.

Comment: i've come across times when i'd want to do this as well.  generally it's when i'm accessing data from a file or other source that's not always consistent/predictable.  Someone could change the column header in a file and now the query is broken.

Comment: This is a great question; even though this will likely never have a good answer. Still worth voting up.

Answer (score 4):

Although you can not use field positions specifiers in the SELECT statement, the SQL standard includes the INFORMATION_SCHEMA where the dictionary of your tables is defined. This includes the COLUMNS view where all the fields of all tables are defined. And in this view, there is a field called ORDINAL_POSITION which you can use to assist in this problem.

If you query

```
SELECT ORDINAL_POSITION, COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE'
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
```

then you can obtain the column names for the ordinal positions you want. From there you can prepare a SQL statement.

Answer (score 2):

You could use temp table as:

```
DECLARE @TB TABLE(Column1 NVARCHAR(50),...)
INSERT @TB
SELECT * FROM student
```

Then use it:

```
SELECT Column1 FROM @TB WHERE Column1='aa'
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's a string you can do this :

```
Select Column1 + '' From Table
```

If it's a number you can do this :

```
Select Column1 + 0 From Table
```

If it's a datetime you can do this :

```
Select dateadd(d, 0, Column1) From Table
```

And similarly for other data types..

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not use the ordinal (numeric) position in the SELECT clause. Only in Order by you can.

however you can make your own column alias...

```
Select Column1 as [1] From Table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use alias:

```
SELECT name AS [1], family AS [2] FROM student WHERE name="X"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just not possible. Unfortunately, they didn't think about table-valued functions, for which information_schema is not available, so good luck with that.